# Excel formula to find the occurrences of the letter "x" in a range

Tags: excel, formula

Tried using this formula to bring back the number of "x"s on tab 2 , which should be 8 and it gave me 2, I know I probably need a LEN in here somewhere but, done racking my brain. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(DASHBOARD!$B$5:$B$11,{"optics"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11,{"x"},0)))
```

picture of tab 1 & tab 2

[image]

Comment: What is he maximum number of Xs in any one given cell?

Answer (score 2):

1. `ISNUMBER(MATCH(DASHBOARD!$B$5:$B$11,{"optics"},0))` can be expressed simply as `(DASHBOARD!$B$5:$B$11="optics")`
2. `ISNUMBER(MATCH(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11,{"x"},0))` is looking for cells that equal just a single `x` not counting the ones.  Instead use `(LEN(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11,"x","")))`

So:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DASHBOARD!$B$5:$B$11="optics")*(LEN(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DASHBOARD!BY5:CB11,"x",""))))
```

[image]